# Run sh script via php script via apache webserver

Tags: php, apache, raspberry-pi, sh

I've written a script to mount a disk when its connected to a volume with a specific UUID.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #run script and store in PATH the path to disks
    pathD=$(python /home/pi/scripts/AUTOMOUNT/disco1.py 2>&1)
    #echo $pathD  ###print disk's path
    #mount it in PATH
    if [ $pathD == 'None'  ]  ###Stop script if disk not present###
    then
        echo 'Disk not present'
        exit
    fi
    sudo mount $pathD /media/Drive1
    echo 'Disco 1 montato'
```

to run this without sudo I've modified the sudoers file, where was added the line

```
    pi ALL= NOPASSWD: /home/pi/scripts/AUTOMOUNT/monta1.sh
```

and the script works fine from shell.

Now I need to run it in a PHP script, which is triggered from the Apache webserver homepage. The script is

```
    <html>
    <body>

    <?php
        $delay = 10;
        if($_POST['button1'] == 'ON')
        {
        //action for ON
        $output1 = shell_exec('sh /home/pi/scripts/PINS/disk1ON.sh');
        echo $output1;
        $output2 = shell_exec('sh /home/pi/scripts/AUTOMOUNT/monta1.sh')
        echo $output2;
        }
        else if ($_POST['button1'] == 'OFF')
        {
        //action for OFF
        $output = shell_exec('sh /home/pi/scripts/PINS/disk1OFF.sh');
        echo $output;
        }
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

and works fine until $output2 command is called. Calling the script monta1.sh (the script written on top) nothing happens ...

I tried to add to sudoers the line

```
    wwwuser ALL=NOPASSWD: /home/pi/scripts/AUTOMOUNT/monta1.sh
```

but nothing happens

How can I make it work ?

Comment: use [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) instead, so you can capture the output AND exit code. without the exit code you're just debugging in the dark.

Comment: I tried : 
exec(sh /home/pi/scripts/PINS/disk1ON.sh', $output , $exit_code);
echo $output;
echo $exit_code;

but page is still empty ...